# Dockerized nginix cannot resolve DNS name

Tags: docker, nginx, dns, reverse-proxy, proget

I'm trying to configure nginx to work as a reverse proxy for the proget application. Everything works fine if I use IP in browser. Unfortunately for some reason it doesn't work at domain name like example.com. I host applications on the digitalocean droplet. I have DNS configured there too.

Nginix configuration below:

```
upstream proget{
  server        proget;
}

server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://proget;
  }
}
```

I create other containers according to the documentation: https://docs.inedo.com/docs/proget/installation/installation-guide/linux-docker

Answer (score 0):

I met similar problem in a k8s cluster before. And I fixed it by adding [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive to my nginx config.

Comment: Doesn't help in this case;/